# How to exclude rows with null values in all columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I writing a view query requiring a very long SQL script with a lot of joining. There are some values lead to null values in all columns coming from one of the tables.

Basically, my question is there any way to exclude results that end up all null?

might system object help in this case?

Comment: it's more than 35 columns, and there are a lot of joining. I'm looking for something dynamic instead of manuale filtering

Comment: then replace NULL values to any constants, filter columns that doesnt contain that constant value

Comment: Are the columns that are showing as NULL nullable or as a result of say a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: It is as result of joining, you hit the point thanks, @Cool_Br33ze

Comment: You want it to drop the columns from the result where all rows are null? It is possible. You would select your query into a temp table, then go over the columns of that table, dropping each based on not getting a 1 from  `SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #Temp WHERE {columnName} IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @MSTQNB if they're as a result of LEFT JOINs then replace with INNER JOINs

Comment: It would have been helpful to see how you build your query. Are you selecting *, are you selecting defined columns, what types of joins do you use. You can of course sanitize table and column names, but please include code in a question like this.

Comment: It's not a personal code, it is for company

Comment: `where coalesce(c1, c2, ... c9) is not null`

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a hack, but you can use `concat()` in the final `WHERE`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,colx varchar(50) ,coly varchar(50), colz int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'aa','bb',25),
(2,'aa',null,50),
(3,null,null,null)

Select *
 From  @YourTable 
 Where concat(colx,coly,colz)>''
```

**Returns **

```
ID  colx    coly    colz
1   aa      bb      25
2   aa      NULL    50
```

Comment: This would exclude null ROWS not null COLUMNS

Comment: @Andrew That's my understanding.

Comment: The way I understand it OP doesn't want columns with all null values.

Comment: That is help thanks a lot, Yes, I'm look for exclude null rows

Answer (score 0):

IS NOT can filter NULL values in the columns

refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql